# how to get the plsql out variable in my webpage

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a plSQL procedure that gives the throughput as output (throughput is a out variable in my procedure) 
  i want to show that output in my webpage 
         could anyone plz tell me the approach

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE pmonit(through1 OUT NUMBER )
AS
  ts1 TIMESTAMP;
  ts2 TIMESTAMP;
 pickid           NUMBER(30);
  no_of_picks  NUMBER(30);
  diff        NUMBER(30);
  rslt      number(30);
  cnt     number(30);
  cnt1     number(30);
  cntc number(30);
BEGIN
  rslt        :=0;
  cnt1       :=0;
  diff       :=0;
  no_of_picks:=0;
  cnt:=0;
  pickid :=0;
  no_of_picks :=0;
  cntc :=0;


  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO no_of_picks FROM prov_adapter_pmonitor;
  select pick_id into pickid from prov_adapter_pmonitor where pick_start_time='24-DEC-14 10.32.48.094000000 AM';
  no_of_picks := no_of_picks + pickid;
  WHILE pickid < no_of_picks
loop
    select count into cntc from prov_adapter_pmonitor where pick_id=pickid;
    if(cntc>0) then
    SELECT pick_start_time
     INTO ts1
     FROM prov_adapter_pmonitor
     WHERE pick_id=pickid    ;

    SELECT pick_start_time
     INTO ts2
     FROM prov_adapter_pmonitor
     WHERE pick_id=pickid+1;
    select sum(
     (extract(hour from ts2)-extract(hour from ts1))*3600+
     (extract(minute from ts2)-extract(minute from ts1))*60+
     extract(second from ts2)-extract(second from ts1))*1000 ms into diff from prov_adapter_pmonitor where
       pick_id=pickid;

    select count into cnt from prov_adapter_pmonitor where pick_id=pickid;
    rslt := rslt+diff;
    cnt1 :=cnt1+cnt;
    pickid  :=pickid       +1;
   else 
   pickid :=pickid +1;
   end if;
end loop;
if(rslt<=0)then 
through1:=0;
 dbms_output.put_line(through1);
else
through1 := cnt1/(rslt/(1000*60)); 
 dbms_output.put_line(through1);
 end if;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
 dbms_output.put_line(through1);
end;
```

Comment: show `plSQL procedure `

Comment: that is my plsql procedure,the out variable through1 calculates the  throughput of my adapter like how many requests are processing per minute.So i want to show that output at webpage

Comment: what is thew web page made out of? is your databae used elsewhere on that page?

Comment: i haven't built webpage yet...please could you tell me the approach that how to have a out variable on the screen

Comment: You're going to require some sort of server side scripting to run the query and insert the result into the page. have you chosen a web server yet? are there other web pages that access the same database server?

Answer (score 0):

run the function in a query.

it seems that you're using oracle.
I think the query goes like this.

```
select pmonit() from dual;
```

Comment: i didnt understand what u said

Comment: it's the same steps as any other SQL query.

Comment: i want out varible value at my webpage